# Replace Wordpress WooCommerce placeholder with div code

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, placeholder

Anyone can help me with this issue?
I want to change the woocommerce placeholder image with a code.
Like im image I attached, but I don't know where I can edit the category placeholder.

Can anyone help me out?
Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to replace the woocommerce default placeholder image, I would suggest to use filter `woocommerce_placeholder_img_src`.

You can change the default placeholder image by putting following code into your `functions.php` file.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_placeholder_img_src','replace_wc_placeholder_img');
if ( ! function_exists( 'replace_wc_placeholder_img' ) ) {
    function replace_wc_placeholder_img() {
        $custom_image = get_template_directory_uri() . '/path-to-your-custom-image';
    }
}
```

Make sure you use the correct path to your image file replacing the placeholder text (`path-to-your-custom-image`) in above function.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello
And thank you
I  don't want to replace the image with another image.
I want to replace the image with a code.

Like this:
http://i.stack.imgur.com/qq8XQ.jpg

- The left image is taken from category image with a different size - to fit there - based on background
- and the category name to appear in that corner, in black arial font
The entire area is clickable, to see the products or subcategories from that page.

Do you know someone who can do it?
I am willing to pay for it.
Thank you